# How to add new Erlang application to a Rebar3 umbrella project?

Tags: erlang, rebar3

I couldn't find it in the docs (or, more probably, I missed it), so I presume these are the steps:

1. Copy existing Erlang application (or create a new one with `rebar3 new app`) into `<umbrella_root>/apps/` (or `<umbrella_root>/libs/`
2. Add the new app to the `relx` section in `<umbrella_root>/rebar.config`:

   ```
    { relx
    , [ {release
        , { your_big_project_name, "0.1.0" }
        , [ your_big_project_name_or_smth_else
          , the_newly_copied_app
        % , sasl
          ]
        }
      , {sys_config, "./config/sys.config"}
      , {vm_args, "./config/vm.args"}
      , {dev_mode, true}
      , {include_erts, false}
      , {extended_start_script, true}
      ]
    }.
   ```
3. Add the new app's required configuration environment variables to `<umbrella_root>/config/sys.config`.
4. If the new app uses a plugin, configure it in `<umbrella_root>/apps/<new_app>/rebar.config`.

Am I close? If yes, does that mean that umbrella applications can be nested? (This should probably be a separate question).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that should be it all you need to include an app file in a release.

Regarding nested umbrella applications, please have a look at the following [thread in rebar3's site](https://www.rebar3.org/discuss/5a7af049ff33cb00457ed915)

**EDIT:**
The linked thread talks about having umbrella apps as dependencies, which is not supported by rebar3. Quote:

> Umbrella applications of that form are just not supported as
> dependencies. Handling versioning and locking for a single
> dependencies that contains multiple apps is not a thing we ever
> figured out, so it's just not doable.

That does not mean that you cannot use some tricks, like using git submodules and multiple [project_app_dirs](https://www.rebar3.org/docs/configuration#directories) configured in the root. For rebar3 those apps will be local apps, you'll need to handle them from 'outside' rebar3, though (not really 'nested' umbrella applications).

Comment: Thanks for the link! I'm going to ask that question separately because it is obviously a big topic by itself.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/27008421)

Comment: @AshwinGeetD'Sa I'll edit the answer to include at least the first thread reply